# How to add multiple rows on dataframe based on a column of distinct values? pandas/python

Tags: python, pandas

So i have a pandas data frame with a few numeric columns and an id column thats a string in Python

```
id  a1  a2 a3 a4 
abc 23 33  33 string
dbc 2  3   3 string
abc 3  4   100 string
```

i want to add all the numeric columns for the same id string.

```
 id  a1 a2 a3  a4 
 abc 26 37 133 string
 dbc 2  3   3  string
```

Is there an elegant way if doing it in pandas or do i have to make a unique list of objects in the first column and loop through them and add them?

Comment: What happens to the strings? Are they always the same for rows with the same `id`?

Comment: Use `groupby` and `agg`.

Comment: I don't care about the string column - i only need the numeric totals. I guess I shouldn't have added that column..